# Is there any difference between "in the start of something" and "at the start of something"?

Tags: prepositions, difference

Is there any difference between *in the start of something* and *at the start of something*? Not long ago I would've thought that *in the start of* was incorrect, but in the 11th episode of the 6th season of *Friends* Joey said exactly that. Here it is:

> Joey: That’s right! I helped you guys out a lot **in the start of** your relationship. Huh? I helped you guys sneak around for like six months, and I looked like an idiot! And I was humiliated. And I only made 200 dollars!

Would the meaning of the sentence change, if he said *at the start of*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good question! Normally *in the start of* would be incorrect. But Joey is speaking informally. If he said *at the start of*, it would mean *at the very beginning of*; but when he says *in the start of*, he means something like *in the early stages of*. So not *only* at the very beginning, but for some time after that too. (For like six months.)

Comment: I don't agree with the second sentence in this answer. Why would *in the start* ***normally*** be incorrect? I also don't agree that it needs to only be informal. If you deleted the second and third sentences (or expanded on them to make them more than just a personal assertion), I'd have no problem with this answer.